# PHP not converting 2 out of 12 months correctly...PHP Bug?

Tags: php

I'm trying to take a complete date from mySQL database (formatted YYYY-MM-DD) and have PHP convert the 2 digit month number to a 3 letter representation and put it in a select box for a user to edit, when the user selects a month it needs to be returned as a 2 digit month number. This code below works great except that for some reason 08 comes back to the user as 08 and not AUG, the same occurs for September however all other months do what I want them to. Do you think this is a glitch with PHP itself? I'm pretty sure I didn't miss anything here.
Thanks in advance!

```
    $endmonth = (substr($record['twpEndDate'], -5, 2));
    $endmonthnumber = (substr($record['twpEndDate'], -5, 2));
    if ($endmonth==00) {$endmonth=''; $endmonthnumber='';}
    else
    if ($endmonth==01) {$endmonth='JAN'; $endmonthnumber='01';}
    else
    if ($endmonth==02) {$endmonth='FEB'; $endmonthnumber='02';}
    else
    if ($endmonth==03) {$endmonth='MAR'; $endmonthnumber='03';}
    else
    if ($endmonth==04) {$endmonth='APR'; $endmonthnumber='04';}
    else
    if ($endmonth==05) {$endmonth='MAY'; $endmonthnumber='05';}
    else
    if ($endmonth==06) {$endmonth='JUN'; $endmonthnumber='06';}
    else
    if ($endmonth==07) {$endmonth='JUL'; $endmonthnumber='07';}
    else
    if ($endmonth==08) {$endmonth='AUG'; $endmonthnumber='08';}
    else
    if ($endmonth==09) {$endmonth='SEP'; $endmonthnumber='09';}
    else
    if ($endmonth==10) {$endmonth='OCT'; $endmonthnumber='10';}
    else
    if ($endmonth==11) {$endmonth='NOV'; $endmonthnumber='11';}
    else
    if ($endmonth==12) {$endmonth='DEC'; $endmonthnumber='12';}
echo "

<select name='twpEndMonth'>
<option value=" .$endmonthnumber. " style='display:none; selected'>" .$endmonth. "</option>
<option value='01'>JAN</option>
<option value='02'>FEB</option>
<option value='03'>MAR</option>
<option value='04'>APR</option>
<option value='05'>MAY</option>
<option value='06'>JUN</option>
<option value='07'>JUL</option>
<option value='08'>AUG</option>
<option value='09'>SEP</option>
<option value='10'>OCT</option>
<option value='11'>NOV</option>
<option value='12'>DEC</option>
</select>";
```

Comment: The search term you're looking for is "octal".

Comment: And the short version is: "don't use leading zeroes in numbers".

Comment: Why would it work for months January through July but not August and September?

Comment: Only works x out of y times... PHP developer... thedailywtf.com/Articles/God-Date-Mangling-101.aspx

Comment: OK so I'm better off using no leading zero and then adding it back in on the form processor?

Comment: @codeguy yup. See e.g. [int variable with leading zero?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6352919)

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
$endmonth = strtoupper(date('M',strtotime($record['twpEndDate'])));
$endmonthnumber = (substr($record['twpEndDate'], -5, 2));
```

If you need a long if list then probably something is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$endmonth = explode("-", $record['twpEndDate']);
$endmonthnumber = '';//your code was getting a pointless number

if($endmonth[1] == '01'){$endmonth='JAN'; $endmonthnumber='01';}
elseif($endmonth[1] == '02'){$endmonth='FEB'; $endmonthnumber='02';}

//and so on
```