# how to show current month value in array

Tags: php, arrays

this is my array value

```
$months = array(01 => "Jan", 02 => "Feb", 03 => "Mar", 04 => "Apr", 05 => "May", 06 => "Jun", 07 => "Jul", 08 => "Aug", 09 => "Sep", 10 => "Oct", 11 => "Nov", 12 => "Dec");
```

my output like this

```
Array ( [1] => Jan [2] => Feb [3] => Mar [4] => Apr [5] => May [6] => Jun [7] => Jul [0] => Sep [10] => Oct [11] => Nov [12] => Dec )
```

WHY?

Comment: augest not display in output array

Comment: you miss one month

Comment: bro i use augest in month array

Comment: did you apply some code before getting your output what you shown to us?

Comment: this is beginning code

Comment: You should maybe use string instead of integer for the keys of your array. It would display properly.

Use "01" instead of 01 when you create your array.

Comment: either use quotes around `01......09` or remove 0 from `01..........09`.check here:-https://eval.in/638552

Comment: Which part exactly are you confused about? Also I don't see how this has anything to do with JavaScript or HTML.

Answer (score 1):

If you want leading zeros you have to use string keys:

```
$months = array("01" => "Jan", "02" => "Feb", "03" => "Mar", "04" => "Apr", "05" => "May", "06" => "Jun", "07" => "Jul", "08" => "Aug", "09" => "Sep", "10" => "Oct", "11" => "Nov", "12" => "Dec");
```

To show current month:

```
echo($months[date('m')]);
```

Comment: woe this is working .......thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the leading zeros in your array indices.
Leading zeros in integer values define a number in `octal` numbering format.

If you use `09` this means that you want to use `9` in octal numbering system, but that system only supports `0` - `7`, so that PHP will convert it to `0`.

Please change your code to:

```
$months = array(1 => "Jan", 2 => "Feb", 3 => "Mar", 4 => "Apr", 5 => "May", 6 => "Jun", 7 => "Jul", 8 => "Aug", 9 => "Sep", 10 => "Oct", 11 => "Nov", 12 => "Dec");
```

Please also have a look at: [int variable with leading zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352919/int-variable-with-leading-zero)

Comment: This is the correct answer since it explains 'why'.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try it.


    $months = array("01" => "Jan", "02" => "Feb", "03" => "Mar", "04" => "Apr", "05" => "May", "06" => "Jun", "07" => "Jul", "08" => "Aug", "09" => "Sep", "10" => "Oct", "11" => "Nov", "12" => "Dec");

    $now = new \DateTime('now');
    $month = $now->format('m');




    echo $months[$month];
```