# Integer value is converting into an unexpected number in PHP

Tags: php

I am facing an unexpected issue in PHP. When I try to echo a number then it is printing a different number on the browser:

```
<?php
    echo 04240;
?>
```

it will print `2208`, which is really surprising.

What is happening here?

Comment: if u put 0 before a number it will be treated as an octal value

Comment: @Sahil you can add your comment as an answer. Also with a link to the docs will make it complete. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [int variable with leading zero?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352919/int-variable-with-leading-zero)

Comment: Why downvoting?? If you know something then it doesn't means everybody knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because initial string has `0` in the first place, PHP consider this number as octal.

When you convert `04240` from octal into decimal like this:

```
0 + 4*8 + 2*8*8 + 4*8*8*8
```

You will get `2208` decimal number.

Comment: I am glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the number starts with a zero (0) then it will be treated as an octal not as an decimal value. See more info in the docs http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php